# cannot find module async with npm install

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

Recently i tried installing npm.
 When ever i try to install npm for node modules,
 i repeatedly getting the error `"Cannot find module async",

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.3.4",
    "jshint": "^2.9.2",
    "karma": "~0.13.15",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs2-launcher": "^0.3.2",
    "lite-server": "2.0.1",
    "traceur": "^0.0.91",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.16",
    "yargs": "^4.7.0",
    "gulp-minify": "0.0.11",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "events": "^1.0.2",
    "fbjs": "^0.3.1",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-toastr": "^0.3.1",
    "ng2-tooltip": "0.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

can any one suggest me some help.........

Comment: what's your package.json?

Comment: i dont have any package,json for my project

Comment: So what do you want to install?

Comment: sry,edited code

Comment: which version of npm do you use?

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to upgrade npm:

For Unix:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

For Windows:
Follow the instructions on: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm